# How to read xml attribute values into c# list

Tags: c#

I have a xml data with below code

```
    <RESULT>
<OperationsRow>
    <Name>John</InteNom>
    <Id>XYV10572</Id>
    <OperationDate>2020-04-14T13:25:41</OperationDate>
    <OperationDetails>welcome to the world</OperationDetails>
    <OperationDesc>ABCDEF</OperationDesc>
    </OperationsRow>

<OperationsRow>
    <Name>Kennedy</InteNom>
    <Id>XYM54572</Id>
    <OperationDate>2018-04-14T13:11:41</OperationDate>
    <OperationDetails>welcome to Newyork/OperationDetails>
    <OperationDesc>ZYX</OperationDesc>
    </OperationsRow>  
</RESULT>
```

How to read this xml attribute values into the list of operations(List) with c# linq

pls help me here.

Thanks

Comment: You will have to research this offline/online, try something after that and then present your tried out code if it is producing any error or undesired output. Then people here will get precise idea on where you are getting stuck and will be happy to help. Try searching for (Reading XMLDocument, Parsing XML etc)

Comment: @new_leaner there are no attributes in your document. You deal only with elements: attributes are optional parts of an element, but there's none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your Operations Class

```
 public class Operations
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string OperationDate { get; set; }
    public string OperationDetails { get; set; }
    public string OperationDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Now what we want is `List<Operations>` from the XML.

Here the full code with LINQ implemantation

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{

class Program
    {

        public static string xml = @"
    <result>
    <OperationsRow>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Id>XYV10572</Id>
        <OperationDate>2020-04-14T13:25:41</OperationDate>
        <OperationDetails>welcome to the world</OperationDetails>
        <OperationDesc>ABCDEF</OperationDesc>
     </OperationsRow>

    <OperationsRow>
        <Name>Kennedy</Name>
        <Id>XYM54572</Id>
        <OperationDate>2018-04-14T13:11:41</OperationDate>
        <OperationDetails>welcome to Newyork</OperationDetails>
        <OperationDesc>ZYX</OperationDesc>
    </OperationsRow>  
    </result>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var operations =
                from operation in doc.Descendants("result").Elements("OperationsRow")
                select new Operations() 
                { 
                    Id = operation.Element("Id").Value,
                    Name = operation.Element("Name").Value,
                    OperationDate = operation.Element("OperationDate").Value,
                    OperationDetails = operation.Element("OperationDetails").Value,
                    OperationDesc = operation.Element("OperationDesc").Value
                };
        }
}
```

You can track the structure:

```
from operations in xml
      .Element("result")       // must be root
      .Elements("OperationsRow")         // only directly children of CompanyInfo
```

or less strictly

```
from employee in xml.Descendants("OperationsRow")    // all employees at any level
```

And then get the information you want:

```
   select new Operations()
   {
       Id = operation.Element("Id").Value,
       Name = operation.Element("Name").Value
        //........
   }
```

Hope this helps.